# Flattening a column in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a column `closed_by` that I need to flatten and put into other fields. 
Previously I was using `df[['assigned_to.Display_value', 'assigned_to.link']] = df.assigned_to.apply(pd.Series)` and that worked well. However in the `closed_by` column the data is not always populated.

The dataset that I have for closed is

```
Closed
{'link': 'https://link/070ac', 'display_value':'Carrie'}
{'link': 'https://link/4981a', 'display_value': 'Vinod'}
{'link': 'https://link/4981a', 'display_value': 'Vinod'}
{'link': 'https://link/4981a', 'display_value': 'Vinod'}
{'link': 'https://link/4981a', 'display_value': 'Vinod'}
``
``
``
``
``
```

This data makes sense because each assignment might not have been closed. What I'm running into is a `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key` which also makes sense because there is no data in the lines that are not closed.

What I'd like to have is something like this with a place holder value in the lines that are not closed. I've put PH in the expected dataset but any placeholder will do.

```
Closed_link           Closed_display_value
https://link/070ac    Carrie
https://link/4981a    Vinod
https://link/4981a    Vinod
https://link/4981a    Vinod
https://link/4981a    Vinod
PH                    PH
PH                    PH
PH                    PH
PH                    PH
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a more pythonic way to do this and if there is please let me know. What I ended up with is below. This creates a placeholder dict, and allows me to set the values. When looping over my column I can set the columns that have a length of 0 (or less though not sure how that'd happen) to the dict we just created.

```
placeholder_dict = {}
placeholder_dict['display_value'] = "Open"
placeholder_dict['link'] = "Open"
for i in range(0, len(df['closed_by'])):
    if len(df['closed_by'][i]):
        continue
    else:
        df['closed_by'][i] = placeholder_dict
df[['closed_by.Display_value', 'closed_by.link']] = df.closed_by.apply(pd.Series)
```

I hope this helps someone else. While not super pythonic I'm sure, it works and allows the data to be set.